# Pandas groupby is very slow for large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code snippet. This seems to be very slow for large dataframe, I am not seeing any opportunity of improvement here. I am not able to use pandarallel as I am already using multiprocessing. Anyway to speed this snippet:

```
def group_func(group):
    school_open = (group['school_open'] == True)
    exam = (group['exam_scheduled'] == True)
    attendance_required = (group['att_flag'] == True)

    score_mask = school_open & exam
    attendance_mask = attendance_required & school_open

    score = group.loc[score_mask, 'ind_score'].mean()
    attendance = group.loc[attendance_mask, 'att'].mean()
    active_day = group[attendance_mask]['dates'].nunique()
    median_score = group.loc[score_mask, 'ind_score'].median()

    return pd.Series({'score': score, 'attendance': attendance, 'active_day': active_day, 'median_score': median_score})

student_consolidated = student_df.groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).apply(group_func)
```

EDIT:
Dataframe for validation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='12/31/2023', freq='D')
data = {'student_name': [fake.name() for i in range(len(date_rng)*100)],
        'dates': np.tile(date_rng, 100),
        'school_open': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100),
        'att_flag': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100),
        'exam_scheduled': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(date_rng)*100),
        'ind_score': np.random.randint(1, 30, size=len(date_rng)*100),
        'att': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100)}

student_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: can you share a testable fragment of `student_df` ?

Comment: You already use `multiprocessing`? Provide your code because `apply` does not use multiprocessing. How many groups do you have, how many records per group?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added testable fragment though a dummy one.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: without multiprocessing, you can compute the masks outside the `groupby` then use `agg` which is faster than `apply`:

```
score_mask = df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled']
attendance_mask = df['att_flag'] & df['school_open']

out = (df.assign(ind_score=lambda x: x['ind_score'].where(score_mask),
                att=lambda x: x['att'].where(attendance_mask),
                dates2=lambda x: x['dates'].where(attendance_mask))
         .groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')])
         .agg(score=('ind_score', 'mean'), attendance=('att', 'mean'),
              active_day=('dates2', 'nunique'), median_score=('ind_score', 'median')))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                           score attendance  active_day  median_score
student_name   dates                                                 
Aaron Anderson 2023-01-31   16.0        0.0           1          16.0
               2023-09-30    1.0        NaN           0           1.0
Aaron Arias    2023-08-31   29.0        0.0           1          29.0
Aaron Atkins   2023-07-31    NaN        NaN           0           NaN
Aaron Baldwin  2023-03-31    NaN        NaN           0           NaN
...                          ...        ...         ...           ...
Zoe Riley      2023-02-28    NaN        NaN           0           NaN
Zoe Rodgers    2023-01-31    NaN        NaN           0           NaN
Zoe Swanson    2023-04-30    NaN        NaN           0           NaN
Zoe Vasquez    2023-03-31   22.0        0.0           1          22.0
Zoe White      2023-01-31    NaN        NaN           0           NaN

[35699 rows x 4 columns]
```

Check:

```
#     v-- agg             apply --v
>>> (out.fillna(-9999) == student_consolidated.fillna(-9999)).all().all()
True
```

Performance:

```
>>> %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_agg(student_df)
3.47 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_apply(student_df)
48.2 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Corralien, I am using multiprocessing in the script and not for groupby, each process does this groupby operation actually.

Comment: So, you can use the rest of the available cpus to do the groupby? Else you have no solution, your code is already vectorized.

Comment: Yes, but can it be done better without multiprocessing!

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer but it hasn't been tested. As @RomanPerekhrest suggests, can you provide a minimal reproducible example, please?

Comment: Added a dummy testable fragment

Comment: I fixed my code and updated my answer, it's clearly faster with agg :)

Comment: @Lata. Did one answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

Try use `np.where` or/and `np.select` if you struggle with performance/large input data.

[Docs for numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

More or less the Reason explained [Why numpy.where is much faster than alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123613/why-numpy-where-is-much-faster-than-alternatives)

Approach (inspired by @Corralien's answer):

```
df = student_df.copy(deep=True)
df['ind_score'] = np.where(df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'], df['ind_score'], np.nan)
df['att'] = np.where(df['att_flag'] & df['school_open'], df['att'], np.nan)
df['dates2'] = np.where(df['att_flag'] & df['school_open'], df['dates'].astype(int)/1000, np.nan)
res = df.groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).agg(
    score=('ind_score', 'mean'),
    attendance=('att', 'mean'),
    active_day=('dates2', 'nunique'),
    median_score=('ind_score', 'median')
)
```

Performance:

```py
In [4]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_apply(student_df)
21.3 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
In [7]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_agg(student_df)
1.26 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
In [10]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_npwhere(student_df)
65.4 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

@Lata if your data fits your RAM it could be better to discard multiprocessing at all.

### Interesting performance tip about `.groupby` and `agg`

Seems like, `.agg` don't play well with heterogeneous data types. And it is related to `None` vs `np.na`.

Performance

```
In [19]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 (df.assign(ind_score=np.where(df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'], df['ind_score'], np.nan)).groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).ag
    ...: g(score=('ind_score', 'mean'),))
54.6 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [20]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 (df.assign(ind_score=np.where(df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'], df['ind_score'], None)).groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).agg(
    ...: score=('ind_score', 'mean'),))
1.25 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Only difference here:

```
# Fast
df.assign(
    ind_score=np.where(
        df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'],
        df['ind_score'],
        np.nan)
) # ...
# Slow
df.assign(
    ind_score=np.where(
        df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'],
        df['ind_score'],
        None)
) # ...
```

The timing of execution suggests that the results of `np.where` with `None` equals to @Corralien `ind_score=lambda x: x['ind_score'].where(score_mask)`. And after that, `.groupby` performs not well.

### full code

```py
Python 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:25:29) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: from faker import Faker
   ...: 
   ...: fake = Faker()
   ...: 
   ...: date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='12/31/2023', freq='D')
   ...: data = {'student_name': [fake.name() for i in range(len(date_rng)*100)],
   ...:         'dates': np.tile(date_rng, 100),
   ...:         'school_open': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100),
   ...:         'att_flag': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100),
   ...:         'exam_scheduled': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(date_rng)*100),
   ...:         'ind_score': np.random.randint(1, 30, size=len(date_rng)*100),
   ...:         'att': np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(date_rng)*100)}
   ...: 
   ...: student_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [2]: # Orig

In [3]: def groupby_apply(student_df):
   ...:     def group_func(group):
   ...:         school_open = (group['school_open'] == True)
   ...:         exam = (group['exam_scheduled'] == True)
   ...:         attendance_required = (group['att_flag'] == True)
   ...: 
   ...:         score_mask = school_open & exam
   ...:         attendance_mask = attendance_required & school_open
   ...: 
   ...:         score = group.loc[score_mask, 'ind_score'].mean()
   ...:         attendance = group.loc[attendance_mask, 'att'].mean()
   ...:         active_day = group[attendance_mask]['dates'].nunique()
   ...:         median_score = group.loc[score_mask, 'ind_score'].median()
   ...: 
   ...:         return pd.Series({'score': score, 'attendance': attendance, 'active_day': active_day, 'median_score': median_score})
   ...:     return student_df.groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).apply(group_func)
   ...: 

In [4]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_apply(student_df)
21.3 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [5]: # Fast

In [6]: def groupby_agg(df):
   ...:     score_mask = df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled']
   ...:     attendance_mask = df['att_flag'] & df['school_open']
   ...:     out = (df.assign(ind_score=lambda x: x['ind_score'].where(score_mask),
   ...:                     att=lambda x: x['att'].where(attendance_mask),
   ...:                     dates2=lambda x: x['dates'].where(attendance_mask))
   ...:              .groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')])
   ...:              .agg(score=('ind_score', 'mean'),
   ...:                   attendance=('att', 'mean'),
   ...:                   active_day=('dates2', 'nunique'),
   ...:                   median_score=('ind_score', 'median')))
   ...:     return out
   ...: 

In [7]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_agg(student_df)
1.26 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [8]: # Furious

In [9]: def groupby_npwhere(df):
   ...:     df = student_df.copy(deep=True)
   ...:     df['ind_score'] = np.where(df['school_open'] & df['exam_scheduled'], df['ind_score'], np.nan)
   ...:     df['att'] = np.where(df['att_flag'] & df['school_open'], df['att'], np.nan)
   ...:     df['dates2'] = np.where(df['att_flag'] & df['school_open'], df['dates'].astype(int)/1000, np.nan)
   ...:     res = df.groupby(['student_name', pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M')]).agg(
   ...:         score=('ind_score', 'mean'),
   ...:         attendance=('att', 'mean'),
   ...:         active_day=('dates2', 'nunique'),
   ...:         median_score=('ind_score', 'median')
   ...:     )
   ...:     return res
   ...: 

In [10]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 groupby_npwhere(student_df)
65.4 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [11]: (groupby_agg(student_df).fillna(-9999) == groupby_apply(student_df).fillna(-9999)).all().all()
Out[11]: True

In [12]: (groupby_npwhere(student_df).fillna(-9999) == groupby_apply(student_df).fillna(-9999)).all().all()
Out[12]: True
```